Cloud Shell Terminal not Activating
My Cloud Shell Terminal just stopped working how it usually does. I see a white screen with no ability to input. Additionally, the shell will not allow me to switch to safe mode or restart, an empty box appears but nothing happens. I'm on the correct project (I have tried others with the same result), and none of my privileges have changed. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.
Cloud Shell Error:

Please see the description.

Had you tried in a different browser? Private session? Cleaning up cookies and those sort of things?

Yes, the only thing that allows it to work is incognito. But even this is inconsistent, it doesn't work every time.

If that is the case it seems to be something on your local. I don't think CloudShell as at whole is with issues.
